# Recargar div con Angular6

Tags: angular

Estoy usando un plugin de pagination para angular6 el cual le dices el número de páginas a mostar:

component.ts

```
public comboItemsPage = '5';
  public configPagination = {
    id: 'custom',
    itemsPerPage: parseInt(this.comboItemsPage, 10),
    currentPage: 1
  };
```

Entonces, coge el array de objetos y va mostrando 5 objetos por página, todo correcto.

Ahora tengo que poner en el html un comboBox para que el usuario seleccione cuántos objetos se muestran por página:

```
            <span>Nº resultados por página: </span>
            <select [(ngModel)]="comboItemsPage" (ngModelChange)="cambiar()" name="select" >
              <option value="5" selected>5</option> 
              <option value="10">10</option>
              <option value="25">25</option>
              <option value="{{ executions.length }}">Todos</option>
            </select>
```

En el NgModelChange compruebo que la variable

```
this.comboItemsPage
```

Está recibiendo bien los cambios, todo correcto, recibo 5,10,25, 90.

El problema es que parece ser que el html ya está pintado, y aunque cambie la variable, no se vuelve a  pintar el html.

¿ Cómo puedo poner un div o algo por encima para que se vuelva a recargar esa parte del .html del angular cuando detecte cambios ? Gracias.

Comment: Puede ser un problema con el change detection, podrías agregar el combo en donde estás detectando el cambio en el modelo?

Comment: Ya está agregado en lo que puse, con el NgModel coge el nuevo valor y arriba del todo, se lo tiene que cambiar a la variable de configPagination

Comment: El método cambiar() no lo veo en el ejemplo. Es lo que está al principio?

Comment: se usa para comprobar que el ngModel recibe el valor del comboBox...

Comment: Puedes crear el ejemplo en Stackblitz para que sea mas facil ayudarte a debugearlo?

Comment: Me parece que estás usando un objeto sin mutarlo correctamente para que el change detect corra, por eso me parece necesitarías forzar el change detect en el cambiar(). De todas maneras, sería bueno tener el ejemplo en Stackblitz